# SIOCSIFADDR: File exists after upgrading kernel

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-kernel

Since upgrading my (Gentoo) kernel from 2.6.38 to 3.3.8 (via oldconfig), I can't get the network on eth0 up anymore. It reports "SIOCSIFADDR: File exists" with a number of other SIOCSIF* errors that seem related. I have the CONFIG_BNX2=y configuration for the Broadcom NetXtreme II NIC that the machine has (which we have been using for years) enabled in the new kernel. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to install the `linux-firmware` package. Apparently, this got split out of the kernel at some point, and I've had to install it manually on boxes that were upgraded from old kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same errors after migrating my system.

For me it was enough to stop the network device (eth0 in my case) in NetworkManager and to stop the init daemon as well:

```
/etc/init.d/net.eth0 stop
```

Restarting the daemon afterwards fixed the problem.